# keep getting segmentation error without the second last return; (makes no sense to me)

Tags: c

can someone explain to me why i need two (return1;) to prevent a segmentation fault. you would figure the last return; would be good enough , no?.

```
for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
{
    string name = get_string("Vote: ");


    if (vote(name))
    {
        printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        i --;
    }
}

bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name , name) == 0)
        {
          candidates[i].votes ++;
          return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What's the array size of `candidates`, and what's the value of `voter_count` ?  As your code stands at the moment, the `for` loop in `vote()` never gets beyond i == 0.

Comment: The second last `return 1;` means the loop executes just once.  When the type is `bool`, use `true` rather than `1` and `false` rather than `0`.

Comment: The first `return 1` means that you only access `candidates[0]` and then return. So one likely problem is that the `candidates` array is less than `voter_count` elements. But you didn't post the code with the definition of `candidates` so we can't point you to the error. Another error could be that `candidates[i].name` is NULL in some element. Conclusion: You need to post more code...

Comment: i believe i fixed the issue by changing "voter_count" (number of votes) to candidate_count (number of candidates)

Comment: That seems dubious -- you would hope you have more voters than candidates in any election -- otherwise every candidate simply votes for themselves and you have a stalemate. (your first `return 1;` nullifies the loop -- it needs to go...)

Comment: Please provide a [example]. And you might like to take the [tour] and to learn [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Probably candidates[1] or candidates[1].name is null or bad.

Please provide the whole program,otherwise it is hard to determine.

BTW - is this c? c doesn't have type string.

Comment: While your answer is likely to be correct, it's more of a guess than an answer. It would be better posted as a comment than an answer. BTW: It's likely based on CS50 due to the use of `string`